# Unable to compile u-boot with hikey_defconfig

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, cross-compiling, u-boot

I just cloned the u-boot from github

```
https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot.git
```

and trying to build it with randomly chosen defconfig (specifically hikey_defconfig).

```
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/linaro-7.2.1-2017.11/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-
make hikey_defconfig
make all
```

This gives me the following error after sometime :

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:36: Error: unexpected character `n' in type specifier
{standard input}:36: Error: bad instruction `b.ne 1b'
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o] Error 1
Makefile:1320: recipe for target 'arch/arm/cpu/armv8' failed
make: *** [arch/arm/cpu/armv8] Error 2
```

Looks like an assembler error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that error from trying to assemble aarch64 code with an ARM (32-bit) assembler?

Comment: `export ARCH=arm` does not look right. Are you sure it is not `aarch64`?

Comment: @PeterCordes : `aarch64`? Ok 2 questions here - 1. How can I know that the code I am trying to assemble is `aarch64`? 2. Other than reading the release notes while downloading the toolchain, how can I know that a pre-installed toolchain compiles for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Regarding (1), `arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o` is indicating Aarch32 or Aarch64 by way of ARMv8. Regarding (2), execute `/opt/linaro-7.2.1-2017.11/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -dumpmachine`. `-dumpmachine` tells you the host you are building for.

Comment: `arm` is traditional 32-bit.  `aarch64` is ARMv8.  You can tell the difference from looking at the source code; if it's using registers like `r0`, it's ARM (or Thumb).  If it's using `x0` / `x0` integer registers, it's AArch64.

Comment: It's confusing that U-Boot hasn't broken out arm64 into its own directory the way Linux has. It would be better to have `arch/arm` and `arch/arm64` than to just have one directory with both.

Comment: Wow lots of new learning for me in one question. Now, how can I build u-boot with `hikey_defconfig` provided I want to build for 32-bit machine.

Comment: Googling the HiKey board, it looks like it has a 64-bit ARM core. Are you sure you want to build for 32-bit?

Comment: I have little idea about arm architecture, but I assume like Intel 64-bit core can run 32-bit programs, I should be able to do that on arm as well. Anyways, I changed my defconfig to a 32-bit core `liteboard-defconfig` and it built all fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hikey 96Boards are using Kirin 920/Kirin 960 SoCs: both are implementing the ARMv8-A 64 bits architecture (Cortex-A73+Cortex-A53), or Cortex-A53 - see [here](https://www.96boards.org/product/hikey/) and [here](https://www.96boards.org/product/hikey960/)

You should therefore use the Linaro aarch64-linux-gnu or aarch64-elf toolchains, not the 32 bits toolchain you were using.

A working command would then be:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf- mrproper hikey_defconfig all
```

You could have checked the architecture you had to compile for by looking at the DTS file referenced in configs/hikey_defconfig at the following line:

```
CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE="hi6220-hikey"
```

arch/arm/dts/hi6220-hikey.dts does include arch/arm/dts/hi6220.dtsi, which does contain the statements telling which architecture the cores included in the Hikey Soc are compatible with:

```
   cpu0: cpu@0 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x0>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu1: cpu@1 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x1>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu2: cpu@2 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x2>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu3: cpu@3 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x3>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu4: cpu@100 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x100>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu5: cpu@101 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x101>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu6: cpu@102 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x102>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };

    cpu7: cpu@103 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a53", "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        reg = <0x0 0x103>;
        enable-method = "psci";
    };
```

This is what could have guided you during your choice of a Linaro toolchain for compiling u-boot for the Hikey board.

Comment: Great answer, I have a question how can I know the toolchain to be used from the cpu architecture ?

Comment: By identifying  the cpu model, and look , say, on Wikipedia, for the version of the arm architecture it does implement: "arm,`cortex-a53`" would require a [AArch64 ELF bare-metal target](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads)  toolchain because it does implement armv8-a. "arm,`cortex-a9`" would require a [AArch32 bare-metal target](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads) because it does implement armv7-a.